# Evitar que se muestre el mensaje al recargar la página: Para mostrar esta página, Firefox necesita enviar información que repetirá cualquier acción

Tags: javascript

Cómo evitar que se muestre el mensaje: `Para mostrar esta página, Firefox necesita enviar información que repetirá cualquier acción (como una búsqueda o una confirmación de compra) realizada anteriormente.` al cargar la web autmáticamente con el siguiente código:

```
<script>
  function reload(tiempo){
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);", tiempo);
  }
  reload(30000);
</script>
```

U otra alternativa que me ayude a evitar el molesto mensaje.

Comment: Este mensaje que dices siempre lo vas a encontrar y no hay manera de quitarlo, la unica forma de que no se muestre es que no uses un formulario para enviar informacion, es un mensaje que aparece cuando intentas volver a atras al enviar un formulario, es cierto que existen los eventos `onbeforeunload` y `onunload` para prevenir quizas el mensaje, pero el problema de usarlos es que creo que aunque se quite el mensaje dejaras inutilizado el boton de volver atras, o pues no se, no lo he probado, pero ya te adelanto que este mensaje esta por defecto en los navegadores.

Comment: Ademas, estos eventos `onbeforeunload` y `onunload` son de los mas propensos a que funcionen "cuando les de la gana", yo en ciertos ejercicios que he realizado me ha pasado que avecez se ejecuta el `beforeunload` o el `unload` y es completamente aleatorio, simplemente no hay garantias de que siempre se ejecuten estos dos (ya sea el uno o el otro, o por lo menos en mi caso y eso que uso chrome y edge chromium).

Comment: Gracias, también leí que usando `GET` en vez de `POST`, voy a intentarlo. Gracias!

Comment: **NI LO INTENTES**, no porfavor no uses `GET`, las peticiones de tipo `GET` son solo para pasar información casi que irrelevante a la persona, la cual realmente no causa daños al modificarse, por ejemplo el numero de pagina o cualquier otro tipo de cosa que pueda ser directamente visible porque no requiere de algun tipo de seguridad, si tu intencion es hacer un sitio web de compras o algo asi, usar peticiones `GET` seria terrible para la seguridad, una catastrofe.

Comment: Aunque si se trata de informacion irrelevante o que no requiere algun tipo de seguridad o no afectaria en nada si se modifica entonces la peticion `GET` sera tu mejor amiga y es completamente viable.

Comment: solo es un numero que indica un tiempo en minutos, podría servir, aunque podría ser manipulable :(

Comment: Es manipulable con una peticion `GET` pero soluciona el problema del cartelito ese.

Comment: Lo ovidaba, estará dentro de un panel de control y quien puede cambiarlo es el mismo que puede poner el valor en el formulario :) así que no hay problema. Gracias